# WPF Image Load to Display Delay

Tags: wpf

There is a slight delay from setting the Source of the image control to the actual displaying.

I need some way to find out when exactly the Image is displayed but I can't seem to find any events that I can hook into.  Does anybody have a way to detect this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your image is some sort of bitmap, Create a BitmapImage object and use its DownloadCompleted event.

Examples, call ReadyToDisplay when the image is ready:

from code:

```
BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage(imageUri);
bmp.DownloadCompleted += ReadyToDisplay;
image.Source = bmp;
```

from XAML:

```
<Image>
   <Image.Source>
      <BitmapImage UriSource="/images/image.png" DownloadCompleted="ReadyToDisplay"/>
   </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

I didn't test those code samples, so they might have typos

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but for some reason the event is not fired for locally loaded images.  A Google also reveals that this event is not reliable.  For me it the event does not fire at all.

Comment: same question here. DownloadCompleted is not fired.

Comment: The event appears to fire for me the first time the image is downloaded, but then after that it does not fire, even if I recreate a new BitmapImage and hook the event a second time.

Comment: I have the same issue. The delay also occurs in case of providing the image as stream (via BitmapImage-instance). It seems to be a delay due to the rendering itself?!